# OS upgrade from Ubuntu Core 15.04 to Ubuntu Core 16.04 support

Tags: ubuntu-core

Is OS upgrade from Ubuntu Core 15.04 to Ubuntu Core 16.04 supported? Will an 15.04 application snap work on 16.04 ubuntu core .

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade your system from Ubuntu Core 15.04 to Ubuntu Core 16 you will need to contact the manufacturer of the device you are targeting. They will have a migration procedure available.

A 15.04 application snap will not work on Ubuntu Core 16. There are migration guides available to help port it over.

Comment: I have Ubuntu Core installed on a Raspberry Pi. There used to be a "snappy" command, but this seems to be gone now? - What replaces it?